# invalid syntax and invalid column

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

[image]

first picture i dont know why i keep getting this error i have no idea how to fix it...either i get this error or invalid column name -_-
[image]
the invalid column error i get only on the item 'tosai'

[image]
this is the coding i used ...checked it multiple time with my notes and i dont see anything wrong here i must be missing something out but i have no idea what is it

Comment: It's always nice to have a "debug" mode where you will print the SQL command. That way, you can easilly see what is wrong with it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! Please don't post screenshots for the reasons outlined in this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530)! Also, re. your problem, could you please print out the actual SQL string that you are sending to the server - that way, we can be of better service!

Comment: what do you mean by print out the SQL string?you mean copy paste the code here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose condition in **' and '**. ( Sql Syntax)

```
delete from [Food] where [Food List] = 'Potato'
```

Comment: it removed the error but its not removing the data...when i debug and click delete it show data deleted but its still on the table

Comment: not a expert on VB, but maybe you need to close the resource in End of Try not in catch

Comment: didnt work....sigh vb is hard -_-